# Java Spring Boot связи между таблицами

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Есть модель, в которой есть связи с полями этой же модели.
[image: Модель KPIRole]
При работе с локальной базой все ок, приложение не создает поля childrenRole и так далее, при этом я могу получить эти Сеты в приложении.

Но когда я заливаю это приложение на сервер Ubuntu, то в той базе он создает эти поля и тогда при получении всех данных из этой модели выходить ошибка, что это поле null.

Структура локальной таблицы:
[image: Структура локальной таблицы]

Структура этой же таблицы на сервере:[image: Структура таблицы на сервере]

Что нужно сделать чтобы эти поля не создавались в базе на сервере?

Comment: Сделайте поля динамическими.

Comment: @RomanC можно поподробнее? пожалуйста

Comment: подробно читай [здесь](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1125595/dinamicheskoe-dobavlenie-poley-v-tablicah-i-metadannye).